# Toggle show/hide <div> element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used following Jquery to show div on button click, with following code. But its not showing the div on button click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addbutton").show();
    $("#addchild").show();

$('#close').click(function(){
$("#addbutton").slideToggle();
});

});
```

Where addbutton is id of button, addchild is div that I want to show, and finally close is id of anchor that will close the div addchild.

**Don't reduce reputation, and if you are mention reason for that.**

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you're trying to achieve, or why it doesn't work...

Comment: please make your question clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to hide and show the div with id "addchild" while clicking the button with id "addbutton":

```
  $('#addbutton').click(function(){
  $("#addchild").slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: Its still not showing output as div.

Comment: your code says the #addchild div is visible when the page loads as you have given $("#addchild").show(); in the document rady function.

Comment: Changing it .show() is still not toggling div tag.

Comment: is div with id "addchild" showing up its contents when the page loads? please edit the question to give the html part also with your current code.   if everything is right , then clciking on the button should hide and show the div on alternate clicks..

Comment: How Can I modify same using double button that if #addbutton show button is shown, #addbutton hide buttons hide. Ad when opposite is shown next becomes shown?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#addbutton").show();
     $("#addchild").hide();

     $('#close').click(function(){ 
         $("#addchild").slideToggle();
     }); 
});
```